# Не работает ИИ на С# не знаю почему

Tags: c#, unity3d, visual-studio, искусственный-интеллект

Вообщем задал движение ИИ так чтобы он ходил на определенное расстояние в итоге враг ходит только в право без движения влево. Убрал ему `Rigibody2D` он просто до бесконечности сквозь блоки идет. а впрочем агресиия работает и возвращение на контроль точки тоже вот видео хода и скрин кода.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
public float speed;

public int ControllPosition;
public Transform point;
bool moveinRight;

Transform player;
public float StopingDistance = 10;

bool chill = false;
bool angry = false;
bool goBack = false;


void Start() {
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Player").transform;
}

void Update() {
    if (Vector2.Distance(transform.position, point.position) < ControllPosition && angry == false) {
        chill = true;
    }

    if (Vector2.Distance (transform.position, player.position) < StopingDistance) {
        angry = true;
        chill = false;
        goBack = false;
    }

    if (Vector2.Distance (transform.position, player.position) > StopingDistance) {
        goBack = true;
        angry = false;
    }

    if (chill == true) {
        Chill ();
    } else if (angry == true) {
        Angry ();
    } else if (goBack == true) {
        GoBack ();
    }
}


void Chill() {
    if (transform.position.x > transform.position.x + ControllPosition) {
        moveinRight = false;
    } else if (transform.position.x < transform.position.x + ControllPosition) {
        moveinRight = true;
    }
    if (moveinRight) {
        transform.position = new Vector2 (transform.position.x + speed * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y);
    } else {
        transform.position = new Vector2 (transform.position.x - speed * Time.deltaTime, transform.position.y);
    }
}


void Angry() {
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards (transform.position, player.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    speed = 9;
}


void GoBack() {
    transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards (transform.position, point.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);
    speed = 4;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
transform.position.x > transform.position.x + ControllPosition
transform.position.x < transform.position.x + ControllPosition
```

Подставь некие значения и посчитай.